# Why no tool buttons above answer field while logged in

Tags: support, bug

Today I faced this strange issue.
There are no quick buttons (linking/image insert) in answer field. The preview field is neither updating.  please see the screen shot,
[image: problem]
But I can see the icons when I am logged out.

Whats going on?

Tested with 
IE8, win 7
Firefox 12,win 7

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or a firewall?

Comment: Yes. Also getting this error in javascript console ->
Error: Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: This looks like a problem with corrupted cache because of a proxy. If you don't have the issue now, you can either close it or delete it. Thanks!

Comment: How can I close it? How it should be marked?